# Firebase database query returns null (function)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add some triggered functions to my firebase account but before that i wanted to learn the basics of firebase queries so i wrote a js file and testing it by writing "node index.js" in my command prompt. Learnt a few basic queries from youtube etc and tried to integrate it in my js file however so far no luck at all. All my queries returns null and i didnt understand what part of it i am doing. Could you please have a look.

Thanks in advance.

My database structure

```
<firebasename>
 users
   edRIPg8BcZU9YPbubp7HtQo7phl1
     sayilar: 2653
     status: "ok"
   hakan
     sayilar: 5000
     status: "waiting"
   mehmet
     sayilar: 7000
     status: "ok"
```

My database rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

My index.js file:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
  apiKey: "<my-api-key>",
  authDomain: "<firebasename>.firebaseio.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<firebasename>.firebaseio.com",

};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
ref = firebase.database().ref();
const events = ref.child('users').child('hakan');
const query =events.orderByChild('status').equalTo('ok').limitToFirst(2);

query.on("value", sorunsuz,sorunlu);

function sorunlu(error) {
  console.log("Something went wrong.");
  console.log(error);
}

function sorunsuz(data) {
  
 
    var fruits = data.val();
    console.log(fruits);
}
```

The command promt shows

> null
>
> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "status" at /users/hakan to your security rules for better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the code is here:

```
ref = firebase.database().ref();
const events = ref.child('users').child('hakan');
```

events targets this part of the data:

```
 users
   hakan
     sayilar: 5000
     status: "waiting"
```

Then you call

```
const query =events.orderByChild('status').equalTo('ok').limitToFirst(2);
```

Which queries the children of `hakan` by their children `status`, which will return null because neither of the keys under `hakan` have a child `status`.
It seems like you want to change `events` to:

```
const events = ref.child('users')
```

Then you would order the children of users by their child `status`.

Comment: You'll also want to add an index under `/users/$userid` to get rid of that warning (and prevent the SDK from downloading all user data and filter on the client).